# Why do different variations of glVertexAttribPointer exist?

Tags: opengl

There are

```
glVertexAttribPointer()
glVertexAttribIPointer()
glVertexAttribLPointer()
```

As far as I know, `glVertexAttribPointer` can be used instead of the other two.

If so, why do the `I` and `L` variations exist?

Comment: This naming convention (capital letters) is shared across different parts of the API, by the way (`glTexParameterIiv (...)`, for instance). **I** means the data is integer and **L** means double-precision floating-point. Otherwise, without those suffixes, you can generally assume that stuff will be converted to single-precision floating-point somewhere in the pipeline regardless which input data type you pass.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I read about this in OpenGL Insights

When using `glVertexAttribPointer()` everything gets cast to a float. While `glVertexAttribIPointer()` can only expose vertex arrays that store integers and `glVertexAttribLPointer()` is only for doubles.

As confirmed by a quote on this [OpenGL.org page](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glVertexAttribPointer):

> For glVertexAttribPointer, if normalized​ is set to GL_TRUE​, it
>   indicates that values stored in an integer format are to be mapped to
>   the range [-1,1] (for signed values) or [0,1] (for unsigned values)
>   when they are accessed and converted to floating point. Otherwise,
>   values will be converted to floats directly without normalization.
>
> For glVertexAttribIPointer, only the integer types GL_BYTE​,
>   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE​, GL_SHORT​, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT​, GL_INT​,
>   GL_UNSIGNED_INT​ are accepted. Values are always left as integer
>   values.
>
> glVertexAttribLPointer specifies state for a generic vertex attribute
>   array associated with a shader attribute variable declared with 64-bit
>   double precision components. type​ must be GL_DOUBLE​. index​, size​,
>   and stride​ behave as described for glVertexAttribPointer and
>   glVertexAttribIPointer.

Answer (score 8):

No, they can't be used instead of each other.

Traditionally, all vertex attributes of the GL are floating-point. The fact that you can input integer data doesn't change that - the data is converted to floating-point on the fly. The `normalized` parameter controls how the conversion is done, if it is enabled, the range of the input type is mapped to the normalized [0,1] (for unsigned types, also called UNORM ing the GL) or [-1,1] (for signed types, also called SNORM), if it is disabled, the value is directly converted to the nearest floating-point value of the input integer.

Since this was the original API, it had to be extended when different attribute data types (integers and doubles) were introduced. Also note that the attribute pointers are independent of the shaders, so the target value cannot be determined by the currently bound shader (if any), as this might be used with different shaders later on. So, the `L` variants id for `double/dvec` attributes, while the `I` variant is for `int/uint/ivec/uvec` attributes.

Answer (score 3):

Have a test and you will understand the difference.

Suppose you are doing transform feedback with the following vertex shader:

```
#version 450 core
layout(location = 0) in int input;
layout(xfb_offset = 0) out float output;

void main()
{
    output = sqrt(input);
}
```

And this is your "vertex data":

```
GLint data[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Then if you setup vertex attributes like this:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 1, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
```

You will get wrong and strange results.

---

If you change this line in the vertex shader

```
output = sqrt(input);
```

to

```
output = sqrt(intBitsToFloat(input));
```

OR

change this line in C++ code:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
                            ^^^^^^^^
                            does not match the real input type
                            but stops glVertexAttribPointer() converting them
```

It will work. But this is not a natural way.

---

Now `glVertexAttribIPointer()` comes to help:

```
--- glVertexAttribPointer(0, 1, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
+++ glVertexAttribIPointer(0, 1, GL_INT, 0, nullptr);
```

Then you will get correct results.

(I struggled for this for a whole afternoon until I found `glVertexAttribIPointer()`.)